# Is it possible to open an another exe (for example command promt) like a content inside of custom Editor Window in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to integrate my desktop application inside of unity editor, is it possible to do that?
For example by using Editor Window as a wrapping of my application?
Any solutions?

Comment: Are you talking about a kind of a level editor where you can produce content for your application inside the application itself? If so, you can give a look to the [runtimeEditor](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/modeling/runtime-editor-64806) asset

Comment: No, I am looking for a possibility to run my c# windows form application inside of custom editor window of unity

Comment: @geg8285 : Please do check if [Unity-WinForms](https://github.com/Meragon/Unity-WinForms) gives you the privilege you needed.

Comment: I would like to do the opposite of the described in https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityasaLibrary-Windows.html, which means to embed the standalone desktop application (like command promt) inside of unity custom editor window.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.